# What is the process of solving the double integral formula $\int_1^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2y}dxdy$?

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, definite-integrals

$$ \int_1^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2y}dxdy $$

my idea：

\begin{align}
&\int_1^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2y}dxdy\\
&=\int_1^{\infty}dx\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2y}dy\\
&=\int_1^{\infty} \color{red}{\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}e^{-x^2y}|^{\infty}_{0} \right) }dx  \\
&= \int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}dx\\
&= 1
\end{align}

in $\color{red}{red}$ part ,**I just treat x as a constant and discard the part where the limit is 0**.

- Is this the right thing to do?

> Can we use the method of treating x as a constant to find the limit in
> double integrals?

- Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: It is the best way I can think of.

Comment: Is the integral really supposed to end with $ \mathrm d x \, \mathrm d y $ as you wrote?  Your calculation would only be correct if it ended with $ \mathrm d y \, \mathrm d x $ instead.

Comment: You have changed the order of integral, but didn't change the bounds.

Comment: Can we use the method of treating x as a constant to find the limit in double integrals?

Answer (score 2):

The first step is invalid, if by the use of the notation $$\int f(x) \, dx$$ we are specifying some function $F(x)$ that satisfies $F'(x) = f(x)$, as opposed to the alternative notation $$\int dx \, f(x).$$  In any case, it is at best notationally inconsistent.

What you are really attempting to do is use [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) to interchange the order of the iterated integrals.  In essence, you are using the theorem to assert that
$$\int_{y=1}^\infty \int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-x^2 y} \, dx \, dy = \int_{x=0}^\infty \int_{y=1}^\infty e^{-x^2 y} \, dy \, dx,$$ and the inner integral is now with respect to $y$.  Hence its calculation yields a function of $x$:

$$\int_{y=1}^\infty e^{-x^2 y} \, dy = \left[-\frac{1}{x^2} e^{-x^2 y}\right]_{y=1}^\infty = \frac{1}{x^2} \left(e^{-x^2} - \lim_{y \to \infty} e^{-x^2 y}\right) = \frac{1}{x^2} e^{-x^2},$$ where the value of the limit is valid for all real $x \ne 0$.  Then the outer integral is
$$\int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2} \, dx.$$  However, this integral does not converge because of the singularity at $0$.

---

That said, based on your calculations, your limits of integration are unclear.  If instead you wanted to evaluate
$$\int_{y=0}^\infty \int_{x=1}^\infty e^{-x^2 y} \, dx \, dy,$$ then this would yield
$$\int_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx = 1$$
as you claimed.  You need to be careful about how you write your limits:  the outermost integral corresponds to the outermost differential, and when the variable of integration is not specified in the limits of integration, the usual interpretation of your integral is that $y \in [1,\infty)$ and $x \in [0,\infty)$.  This is why, despite having been told that my use of such notation as
$$\int_{x=a}^b f(x) \, dx$$ is redundant and verbose, I continue to do it for pedagogical purposes, as well as for ease of reading.  Since we read from left to right, such notation makes it easier for students to immediately see how the region of integration is specified.  And in your case, such notation would eliminate the ambiguity.